# What's the best/fastest/most economical way to install an IP track tool on Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Let's say that I want to track the IP of users and restrict specific users from visiting my website.

Off the top of my head, I can probably call something like `this.connection.clientAddress` via a Meteor method on the server and get access to the user's IP address and then store that IP address on a MongoDB document. Then have each visitor's IP checked against the existing banned IP's and restrict their access accordingly.

But my thinking is that this would be a costly and slow process once we get into the tens of thousands of ID's and having to call and access a MongoDB document for every single user seems like a really bad idea.

Is there any better way to get this done without having to constantly call MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the IP Address when someone logs in via [Accounts.onLogin](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsCommon-onLogin) and update the user's document accordingly.

Comment: I'm strictly talking about non-users. Sorry for being confusing in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how often you need to update the list of IPs, you could instead use a static file at a separate URL to retrieve the list of IPs and cache them on the server.

For instance, create a file in an S3 bucket in AWS (https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/restricted-ips.json). When your application is accessed, it can retrieve this file, cache it on the server (for a given amount of time based on your needs), and check the client's IP against that list. When you wish to add or remove an IP from the restricted IPs list, you just need to update the file, and any instance of your application will receive the updated list after the cache expires.

Of course, if this list is updated infrequently, you could also bake it into the application itself. However, that would require a re-deploy whenever you need to update the IP list.